# Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError Neo4j Error

Tags: memory, neo4j, out-of-memory

I'm using neo4j-community-3.1.4 zip for windows 
With a laptop of i7 2.4GHz and 8G Ram , and trying to integrate a large network in neo4j.
and I'm getting this error

```
 Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError
```

I have tried to increase the max size with uncommenting  the following lines , yet I'm still getting the same error

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10000m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=16000m
dbms.jvm.additional=-Xss2M
```

How do I resolve this 
Query :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///links.csv'
AS line

MERGE (n1:Node {NodeID: line.p1, NodeName: line.p1})
MERGE (n2:Node {NodeID: line.p2, NodeName: line.p2})
MERGE (n1)-[:ACTING_WITH {Score: TOFLOAT(line.combined_score)}]->(n2);
```

Comment: can you share your query ?

Comment: @TomažBratanič , I edited the question adding the query

Comment: you set minimum heap size 10g, but you only have 8g computer... this is probably the case, lower it to 1g and set max heap size to like 5g

Comment: I changed the version and it worked. but it is still loading very slow I do't know if  it is normal